# How can I get acceleration ground truth from VICON?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear, ROS people.

I have a question about acceleration ground truth.

We have VICON system which can provide position and angles.

In order to obtain linear acceleration, double differentiation is applied to position data. Computed the acceleration, however, looks very noisy. I also tried to apply median filter but no success.
Is there anyone who knows how to get nice acceleration like the linked paper?

http://www.xsens.com/images/stories/PDF/Comparison%20of%20three%20measurement%20systems,%20Vicon%20vs%20Xsens%20vs%20Kionix.pdf

Maybe the possible answer would be "apply low-pass filter with 4th_order Butterworth filter with 6Hz cutoff frequency".

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36963/how-can-i-get-acceleration-ground-truth-from-vicon?/) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

My advice would be to capture the data by running the cameras as quickly as possible without sacrificing strobe illumination - This depends on the type of camera.

Ideally, any filter algo needs to incorporate terms for the motion model of the object being tracked. It latency is not so important, smoothing functionality is available within Vicon Tracker that implements a simple moving average smoothing algorithm, you can set the window of this filter to as many as is comfortable for your application.

Regards,
Warren Lester

---

Originally posted by [warren.lester@vicon.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/2707/warren.lester@vicon.com/) with karma: 46 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2012-06-25**:
Thank you for your reply. I didn't quite get how to obtain ground truth acceleration from your reply. We have VICON system, it called gSpeak system that uses VICON camera but does not have Vicon Tracker unfortunately. It wraps Vicon software. http://oblong.com/

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2012-06-25**:
We only can log position (x,y,z) and orientations (roll,pitch,yaw). It seems to apply a filter and regression to obtain acceleration and velocity. Cheers.